# how to return the the array from node.js function which is inside another function

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function comm_price(comm){
list_comm = [];
k=0
var scraper = require('table-scraper');
scraper.get('http://somewebsite.com')
.then (function(tabledata){
    for(i=0;i<tabledata[14].length;i++){
        if(tabledata[14][i][1].includes(comm)){
            list_comm[k] = (tabledata[14][i]);
            k+=1;
        }
    }
    return list_comm;
});

}
var lis = [];
lis = comm_price('Pepper');
```

how to assign the returned data to a variable ?
Im new to javascript , since there is function inside the function , im getting pretty confused in assigning the return data to a variable.

Comment: you need to return something directly from `comm_price` function - but it WILL be a promise in this case, so you wont be able to `lis = comm_price('Pepper');` - unless you expect `lis` to be a Promise

Comment: `lis = comm_price('Pepper')` is empty , but when i log `list_comm` instead of return , im getting the data which i need ! @Jaromanda X

Comment: yes, did you read my comment? you don't return anything from `comm_price` - so of course lis is `undefined` .... but you can only return a promise from `comm_price` - so you'll need to rewrite your code, unless you expect `list` to be a Promise